# Covariance between Brownian motion and Brownian bridge

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, covariance

Suppose I have a Brownian motion $B_1(1)$ and a Brownian Bridge $BB(\tau) = B_2(\tau) - \tau B_2(1) $. How can I show that they are independent?

I know that it is enough to show that their covariance is $0$ for independence, as they are normally distributed. So, we have
$$ Cov(B_1(1),B_2(\tau)-\tau B_2(1)) = Cov(B_1(1),B_2(\tau)) - \tau Cov(B_1(1),B_2(1)). $$ How can I show that this is equal to $0$?

Comment: How $B_1$ and $B_2$ are related?

Comment: @NCh All that is known about $B_1$ and $B_2$ is that they both result from applying a Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: If you know nothing about joint distribution of two random variables, you cannot find covariance.

Comment: So, to be able to show independence, we need the joint distribution function or that $B_1 = B_2$. But that last part would normally not be the case, even though they both result from the same CLT? @NCh

Comment: Is $B_1(1)$ a type, or you're just considering a Brownian motion at time $t=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Central Limit theorem gives you convergence *in law*.

You may so consider an other Brownian motion $\tilde{B}^1(t)$, with the same law of $B^1(t)$ (i.e. simply a Brownian motion) and *independent* of $B^2(t)$.

So you can proove that $\tilde{B}^1(t)$ is independent of $BB(τ)$.

Comment: So, if I apply a Central Limit Theorem twice to a certain sum of random variables, the resulting Brownian motions are always independent?

Comment: You can choose them to be independent, because you just have convergence in law: you have information on the probability measure, not ω by ω